# Why is List<string>.Sort() slow?

Tags: c#, string, performance, list, comparison

So I noticed that a treeview took unusually long to sort, first I figured that most of the time was spent repainting the control after adding each sorted item. But eitherway I had a gut feeling that `List<T>.Sort()` was taking longer than reasonable so I used a custom sort method to benchmark it against. The results were interesting, `List<T>.Sort()` took ~20 times longer, that's the biggest disappointment in performance I've ever encountered in .NET for such a simple task.

My question is, what could be the reason for this? My guess is the overhead of invoking the comparison delegate, which further has to call `String.Compare()` (in case of string sorting). Increasing the size of the list appears to increase the performance gap. Any ideas? I'm trying to use .NET classes as much as possible but in cases like this I just can't.

Edit:

```
    static List<string> Sort(List<string> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

        List<string> _list = new List<string>(list.Count);
        _list.Add(list[0]);

        int length = list.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            string item = list[i];

            int j;

            for (j = _list.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (String.Compare(item, _list[j]) > 0)
                {
                    _list.Insert(j + 1, item);

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (j == -1)
            {
                _list.Insert(0, item);
            }
        }

        return _list;
    }
```

Comment: How about providing code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Any snippet that would reproduce some arbitrary list sorting using built in methods being slow and your implementation being 20x times faster?

Comment: Also, instead of using custom methods of benchmarking your code, use the built-in tools provided in Visual Studio which can give you an accurate visualization of your time-issues.

Comment: Microsoft would like to have it too ;)

Comment: Also, how big is this list we're talking about?

Comment: @Servario 5040 elements in the test where the custom method was ~20 times faster

Comment: And how long does it take to sort 5040 items... the blink of an eye? Is this the critical path? Does the speedup really matter? How does linq's `OrderBy` compare?

Comment: I still don't have a full picture of the code. Are you sure that your code wasn't dynamically updating the view as the control was sorting the items? (and hence the time was spent displaying the changes)

Comment: @zerkms Here is the full test http://pastebin.com/CpykyCjH

Comment: Have you tried the stringcollection?

Comment: It's not possible that your `O(n ^ 2)` implementation was faster (not even 20x but faster at all) than MS's quick sort (?) one.

Comment: @Sevario See the link I just posted

Comment: @zerkms Try it. I doubt that sorting is possible without a O(n^2) method anyway.

Comment: "I doubt that sorting is possible without a (n^2) method anyway" --- o_O There are algorithms that run even in `O(n)`

Comment: Unbounded sorting algorithms can run with a best min of O(nlogn). In cases in which you have knowledge on the input you can optimize it and run under that boundary.

Comment: @zerkms, not in the general case. AFAIK the best sort algorithms run in `O(n log n)` in the average case. Anyway, I thought there had to be some kind of mistake in the benchmark, but I can't find it... `List<T>.Sort` really is slower...

Comment: Please post the code used for the benchmark.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: I didn't say about general case. I replied to a false statement that "I doubt that sorting is possible without a (n^2)". Which is definitely possible to do, even for `O(n)` time

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I can assure you that the benchmark is implemented correctly. What you should note however is the `Console.WriteLine(list.Count)` statement, it can be mistaken for a benchmark result.

Comment: http://ideone.com/vfbmXn --- on ideone `.Sort()` wins (had to reduce number of runs though since it times out otherwise)

Comment: @zerkms No according to stdout the custom method is 9 times faster

Comment: Could someone doublecheck that the code posted on PasteBin is running several times on an already sorted list? I was doing that when my power died on me.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: Before blaming `List.Sort`, try comparing integers instead of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't had the time to fully test it because I had a blackout (writing from phone now), but it would seem your code (from Pastebin) is sorting several times an already ordered list, so it would seem that your algorithm could be faster to...sort an already sorted list. In case the standard .NET implementation is a Quick Sort, this would be natural since QS has its worst case scenario on already sorted lists.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger, it's pretty close to already sorted.  This is why the first run on your algorithm is slower than subsequent runs, even if you properly warm up the VM first by running `Method1` and `Method2` before measuring.  Thus Saverio's answer is correct in that your implementation handles lists that are close to already sorted better than quicksort -- but quicksort handles the average input far better.

Comment: Yes, the problem with @Leopold's code is that it creates a list and then sorts it. `Method2` does an in place sort - the resulting sorted list is then used in the benchmarking loops. When using the unsorted list to benchmark, MS's code is much faster.

Answer (score 9):

Answer: It's not.

I ran the following benchmark in a simple console app and your code was slower:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long totalListSortTime = 0;

        long totalCustomSortTime = 0;

        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c++)
        {
            List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                var rando = RandomString(15);
                list1.Add(rando);
                list2.Add(rando);
            }

            Stopwatch watch1 = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();

            watch2.Start();
            list2 = Sort(list2);
            watch2.Stop();
            totalCustomSortTime += watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            watch1.Start();
            list1.Sort();
            watch1.Stop();
            totalListSortTime += watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;



        }

        Console.WriteLine("totalListSortTime = " + totalListSortTime);
        Console.WriteLine("totalCustomSortTime = " + totalCustomSortTime);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: And to satisfy the Q&A nature of stackoverflow it could be a good idea to put the answer for the only question: "Why is List<string>.Sort() slow?" as something like "It's not" PS: oh Wellington hi ))

Comment: Btw, curious how faster it is in a release build please?

Comment: I tried your method and the result was as you suggested, appearantly the randomness matters to .NETs sort mechanism. I figured this is what Saverio meant to say. Eitherway problem solved.